# Bridge table for many-to-many relationship

Tags: powerbi, many-to-many, star-schema-datawarehouse, kimball

I'm confused about what the strucutre of the the bridge table.

star schema book is stucturing the bridge table with a group_key

example, if i have
fact_orders  ( order_sk ,  order_nk, amount, **group_key**)
dim_sales_person ( **sales_person_SK**, sales_person_nk, name)

the bridge_table ==>
orders_salesperson_bridge_table : ( **group_key**, **sales_person_SK**)

[image]

FROM any other source, ( google, youtube,..), the definition of the bridge table :
Junction table in a database, also referred to as a Bridge table or Associative Table, bridges the tables together by referencing the primary keys of each data table.

strucutre :
fact_orders  ( **order_sk** ,  order_nk, amount)
dim_sales_person ( **sales_person_SK**, sales_person_nk, name)

bridge table --> orders_salesperson_bridge_table : ( **Order_id**, **sales_person_SK**)

when should i choose each technique ? and why ?

thanks for any help,

Comment: What's the cardinality of the relationship between ORDER_FACTS and SALES_GROUP?  Either the ERD is wrong or you're missing a table in the model.

Comment: this is a dimensional model not an ER model.  i think i forgot the mention that.

Comment: an the Sales_Group table in the image is the bridge table

Comment: And what's the cardinality of the relationship between ORDER_FACTS and SALES_GROUP?

Comment: A many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

The SALES_GROUP table is there to allow you to allocate the value of a sale proportionately to multiple sales people. So in your example the sales amount of 1000 would be allocated as 750/250 between the 2 sales people